# React Native Screen not coming from left to right

Tags: reactjs, react-native, uinavigationcontroller, navigation-drawer

I am starting with ReactNative Implementation of my app.

I have a Home screen which has Hamburger icon on it.

On click of this hamburger icon, a navigation screen should come from left to right.

This should be the expected outcome.

Below is the my code -

```
navigateTo(route) {
    this.props.navigator.push({
        name:route
    });
}

openSideMenu(){
    this.navigateTo(constants.SCREENS.SIDEMENU);
}
```

So, When I am clicking on the icon, the navigation screen is coming from Right to left.

So my question is , how do I get the expected outcome.

I have -

```
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
"react-native": "0.44.0",
"react-native-deprecated-custom-components": "^0.1.1",
```

Thanks,

Comment: Are you trying to open something like menus on the click of your icon ?

Comment: @AkshayRao : Yes, I need to open side menu screen which I have created.

Comment: if you are looking for drawer then you can use drawernavigator which will slide from left to right, if not then let me know .